# Correct way to use ObservableAsPropertyHelper and this.WhenAny on a ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, reactiveui

Say I have a menu for a sketching pad. It has a toolbar with 3 toggle buttons: Pencil, Pen, Eraser. Only one of the 3 tools can be selected at any time and no tools selected is also a legit option.

My VM backing needs to keep track of the selected state.  Being an observable is a big plus as other VMs will need to know the state too.  I think I would like to use an enum. Something to the effect of

```
enum SelectedTool
{
  None=0,
  Pencil,
  Pen,
  Eraser
}
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to set up this VM using a ReactiveObject.  I think that the SelectedTool state variable should be readonly and set upon the tool selection (should this be ObservableAsPropertyHelper?).  I would also like the initial state of the enum to be None.  I also am not sure if each button should have a bool ReactiveProperty or not for backing. If those bool backings exist, then I am going to have to keep the state consistent in the VM, which could be a pain as more tools are added.  I am wondering if there is a way for me to use a WhenAny on the bools to set the appropriate state.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that the SelectedTool state variable should be readonly and set upon the tool selection (should this be ObservableAsPropertyHelper?)

I would actually drive this the other way around - the SelectedTool as an Enum should be the Source Of Truth™, and have the button state be a reflection of that.

```
var pencilToggled = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedTool == SelectedTool.Pencil);

// We can only toggle Pencil when it's not currently toggled
var togglePencil = ReactiveCommand.Create(pencilToggled.Select(x => x != true));
togglePencil.Subscribe(_ => this.SelectedTool = 
    (this.SelectedTool == SelectedTool.Pencil ? SelectedTool.None : SelectedTool.Pencil));
```

You could get super clever and use the four commands + `Merge` + `ToProperty` to make this fully Functional, but you wouldn't get much benefit out of it imho.

Comment: I am getting closer to understanding, but unless I am missing something this code will prevent me from un-toggling the pencil. It is viable that no tool is toggled (but I don't want a "None" button that clears state).  I am also missing the binding to view part.  What does my xaml bind to? Or are you suggesting the binding should be wired in the code behind? I am not sure this code will allow the following: if the pencil is toggled and then the pen is clicked the pencil should un-toggle and the pen should be selected. Thanks

Comment: In the CodeBehind, you'd use WhenAny + BindTo, super similar to the `pencilToggled` line

Comment: "I am getting closer to understanding, but unless I am missing something this code will prevent me from un-toggling the pencil." Fixed up

Comment: That worked. The only thing that I am clear on is the can execute for the Create. If I make it only able to toggle when it's not toggled then it will prevent me from un-toggling.  Am I missing something? If I take that piece out I get my expected behavior.

Comment: Yes you should now take out that part